# How do I use LIMIT on the number of rows used by GROUP BY

Tags: postgresql

I have a large table of inter-related entries (too large to simply query them all and group them).  I would like to page through them, but I want to make sure all my groups contain all the related entries, with the total number of rows used to generate those groups limited.  The groups are different sizes, so simply limiting the number of groups returned does not guarantee a set that is small enough to process.

In pseudo-code, give me all the complete groups (using GROUP BY) that can be generated using no more than N rows.  Then I need to process the next "page" (using OFFSET?).  My current query to process all the rows at once (takes WAY too long on a large table) looks like this:

```
select addressresult->'matchElements' as match, 
       addressresult->'foundElements'->'element0'->>'type' as type, 
       array_agg(id) as ids, 
       count(id) as items 
from address 
group by match, type 
having count(id) >= 5;
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your question by showing us some sample data.  Does your table have a column which could be used to order within each group to determine the first, second, etc. N groups of records?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.